# Mimicking SQL Outer apply with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I'm having a bit of the trouble with translating following  stored procedure to into LINQ.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT a0.[recid] AS 'Id'
    ,a0.[latitude] AS 'Latitude'
    ,a0.[longitude] AS 'Longitude'
    ,a0.[countryregionid] AS 'CountryCode'
    ,a0.[level_] as 'Level'
    ,case 
        when wht.[disinfection] is null
        then 0
        else wht.[disinfection]
    end as 'Disinfection'

    ,case when wd1.[fromtime] is null then '' else CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, wd1.[fromtime] * 1000, 0), 108) end as 'MondayOpen'
    ,case when wd1.[totime] is null then '' else CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, wd1.[totime] * 1000, 0), 108) end as 'MondayClose'

    ,case when wd2.[fromtime] is null then '' else CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, wd2.[fromtime] * 1000, 0), 108) end as 'TuesdayOpen'
    ,case when wd2.[totime] is null then '' else CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, wd2.[totime] * 1000, 0), 108) end as 'TuesdayClose'

    ,case when wd3.[fromtime] is null then '' else CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, wd3.[fromtime] * 1000, 0), 108) end as 'WednesdayOpen'
    ,case when wd3.[totime] is null then '' else CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, wd3.[totime] * 1000, 0), 108) end as 'WednesdayClose'

    ,case when wd4.[fromtime] is null then '' else CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, wd4.[fromtime] * 1000, 0), 108) end as 'ThursdayOpen'
    ,case when wd4.[totime] is null then '' else CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, wd4.[totime] * 1000, 0), 108) end as 'ThursdayClose'

    ,case when wd5.[fromtime] is null then '' else CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, wd5.[fromtime] * 1000, 0), 108) end as 'FridayOpen'
    ,case when wd5.[totime] is null then '' else CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, wd5.[totime] * 1000, 0), 108) end as 'FridayClose'

    ,case when wd6.[fromtime] is null then '' else CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, wd6.[fromtime] * 1000, 0), 108) end as 'SaturdayOpen'
    ,case when wd6.[totime] is null then '' else CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, wd6.[totime] * 1000, 0), 108) end as 'SaturdayClose'

    ,case when wd7.[fromtime] is null then '' else CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, wd7.[fromtime] * 1000, 0), 108) end as 'SundayOpen'
    ,case when wd7.[totime] is null then '' else CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, wd7.[totime] * 1000, 0), 108) end as 'SundayClose'
FROM [dbo].[address] AS a0

LEFT JOIN  GIR_WashhouseTable as wht on wht.[recid] = a0.[addrrecid]

OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1
        awt0.[fromtime]
    ,   awt0.[totime]
    FROM [GIR_AddressWorkTime] as awt0
    WHERE awt0.[dataareaid] = 'v22'
    AND awt0.[active] = 1
    AND awt0.[weekday] = 1
    AND awt0.[refrecid] = a0.[recid]
) as wd1

OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1
        awt0.[fromtime]
    ,   awt0.[totime]
    FROM [GIR_AddressWorkTime] as awt0
    WHERE awt0.[dataareaid] = 'v22'
    AND awt0.[active] = 1
    AND awt0.[weekday] = 2
    AND awt0.[refrecid] = a0.[recid]
) as wd2

OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1
        awt0.[fromtime]
    ,   awt0.[totime]
    FROM [GIR_AddressWorkTime] as awt0
    WHERE awt0.[dataareaid] = 'v22'
    AND awt0.[active] = 1
    AND awt0.[weekday] = 3
    AND awt0.[refrecid] = a0.[recid]
) as wd3

OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1
        awt0.[fromtime]
    ,   awt0.[totime]
    FROM [GIR_AddressWorkTime] as awt0
    WHERE awt0.[dataareaid] = 'v22'
    AND awt0.[active] = 1
    AND awt0.[weekday] = 4
    AND awt0.[refrecid] = a0.[recid]
) as wd4

OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1
        awt0.[fromtime]
    ,   awt0.[totime]
    FROM [GIR_AddressWorkTime] as awt0
    WHERE awt0.[dataareaid] = 'v22'
    AND awt0.[active] = 1
    AND awt0.[weekday] = 5
    AND awt0.[refrecid] = a0.[recid]
) as wd5

OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1
        awt0.[fromtime]
    ,   awt0.[totime]
    FROM [GIR_AddressWorkTime] as awt0
    WHERE awt0.[dataareaid] = 'v22'
    AND awt0.[active] = 1
    AND awt0.[weekday] = 6
    AND awt0.[refrecid] = a0.[recid]
) as wd6

OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1
        awt0.[fromtime]
    ,   awt0.[totime]
    FROM [GIR_AddressWorkTime] as awt0
    WHERE awt0.[dataareaid] = 'v22'
    AND awt0.[active] = 1
    AND awt0.[weekday] = 7
    AND awt0.[refrecid] = a0.[recid]
) as wd7

WHERE a0.[dataareaid] = 'v22' 
AND a0.[active] = 1
AND a0.[level_] <> 0
AND a0.[type] = 153 
AND a0.[ADDRTABLEID] = 52411
AND a0.[countryregionid] IN 
('AT', 'BE', 'BG', 'HR', 'CZ', 'EE', 'FR', 'DE', 'GR', 'HU', 'IE', 'IT', 'LV', 'LT', 'LU', 'NL', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'SK', 'SI', 'ES', 'LI', 'MC', 'SM', 'CH', 'GB', 'DK') -- AIO-833
order by COUNTRYREGIONID
```

so the problem here is outer apply. I've researched ways to mimic outer apply via LINQ and seen that let keyword helps you do that. but in my case it was not useful.
so I tried to do it like this

```cs
var query = 
    from address in _context.Address
    join washHouse in _context.GirWashhousetable
    on address.Addrrecid equals washHouse.Recid into whtGroup
    from washHouse in whtGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join workTime in _context.GirAddressworktime
    on address.Recid equals workTime.Refrecid into workTimeGroup
    from workTime in workTimeGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where address.Dataareaid == "v22"
        && address.Active == 1
        && address.Level != 0
        && address.Type == 153
        && address.Addrtableid == 52411
        && _countryCodesForWashStations.Contains(address.Countryregionid)
        && workTime.Dataareaid == "v22"
        && workTime.Active == 1
    let mondayWorkTime = workTimeGroup.FirstOrDefault(wt => wt.Weekday == 1)
    // Repeat similar logic for other days...
    select new WashingStationsResult
    {
        Id = address.Recid,
        Latitude = address.Latitude,
        Longitude = address.Longitude,
        CountryCode = address.Countryregionid,
        Level = address.Level,
        Disinfection = washHouse.Disinfection,
        MondayOpen = mondayWorkTime != null ? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(mondayWorkTime.Fromtime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss") : string.Empty,
        MondayClose = mondayWorkTime != null ? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(mondayWorkTime.Totime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss") : string.Empty,
        // Repeat similar logic for other days...
    };
```

It works if there is only one let but if I repeat some for other days also Im getting the empty list as a response. Im not sure why. can someone suggest what could be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Just use the sql?

Comment: Which ORM do you use and which version?

Comment: I use entity framework 6.0.0

Comment: EF6... well will prepare answer, but EF6 has really bad SQL generator, who knows how it will be closer to your original SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For OUTER APPLY you have to use different technique: [Collection selector references outer in a non-where case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#collection-selector-references-outer-in-a-non-where-case)

```cs
var query = 
    from address in _context.Address
    join washHouse in _context.GirWashhousetable
        on address.Addrrecid equals washHouse.Recid into whtGroup
    from washHouse in whtGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from mondayWorkTime in _context.GirAddressworktime
        .Where(workTime => address.Recid == workTime.Refrecid 
            && workTime.Dataareaid == "v22"
            && workTime.Active == 1
        )
        .Take(1)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
            
    // Repeat similar logic for other days...

    where address.Dataareaid == "v22"
        && _countryCodesForWashStations.Contains(address.Countryregionid)
        && address.Active == 1
        && address.Level != 0
        && address.Type == 153
        && address.Addrtableid == 52411
    select new WashingStationsResult
    {
        Id = address.Recid,
        Latitude = address.Latitude,
        Longitude = address.Longitude,
        CountryCode = address.Countryregionid,
        Level = address.Level,
        Disinfection = washHouse.Disinfection,
        MondayOpen = mondayWorkTime != null ? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(mondayWorkTime.Fromtime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss") : string.Empty,
        MondayClose = mondayWorkTime != null ? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(mondayWorkTime.Totime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss") : string.Empty,
        // Repeat similar logic for other days...
    };
```

For simplyfying query, you can prepare recordset with predefined filters:

```cs
var workTimes = _context.GirAddressworktime
    .Where(workTime => 
            && workTime.Dataareaid == "v22"
            && workTime.Active == 1
        );

var query = 
    from address in _context.Address
    join washHouse in _context.GirWashhousetable
        on address.Addrrecid equals washHouse.Recid into whtGroup
    from washHouse in whtGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
    from mondayWorkTime in workTimes
        .Where(workTime => address.Recid == workTime.Refrecid && workTime.WeekDay == 1)
        .Take(1)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    // Repeat similar logic for other days...

    where address.Dataareaid == "v22"
        && _countryCodesForWashStations.Contains(address.Countryregionid)
        && address.Active == 1
        && address.Level != 0
        && address.Type == 153
        && address.Addrtableid == 52411
    select new WashingStationsResult
    {
        Id = address.Recid,
        Latitude = address.Latitude,
        Longitude = address.Longitude,
        CountryCode = address.Countryregionid,
        Level = address.Level,
        Disinfection = washHouse.Disinfection,
        MondayOpen = mondayWorkTime != null ? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(mondayWorkTime.Fromtime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss") : string.Empty,
        MondayClose = mondayWorkTime != null ? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(mondayWorkTime.Totime).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss") : string.Empty,
        // Repeat similar logic for other days...
    };
```

Comment: thanks this is really nice way to solve it.  I appreciate your time

Comment: Thx, helped me a ton to fix a similar issue